# Include two files one by one with a ratio of 4 :1

Tags: php

I got two files file4.php and file1.php

Using **INCLUDE** how do I put them in a ratio that if file4.php shows up 4 time then file1.php should show up 1 time to a ratio of 4:1. What will be the best practice?

```
<?php 
  {
    include("file4.php");

} else {

    include("file1.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: What? So... every time a certain file is included, you want to automatically include another file 4 times? There's no best practice for that; people don't do that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'shows up 4 time'?

Comment: Oh ok I get it now. You want to include a different file (randomly?) and have one file show up 4 times as much as the other?

Comment: Ok let me explain, I got two different ads so I want to rotate in a loop by 4:1 ratio let's say a page had 5000 pageviews so file4.php will be shown 4000 times while file1.php will be shown 1000 times.

Comment: @SupremeDud's answer is the way to go, then.

Comment: Keep in mind my answer will approximate the ratio, with the approximation getting better with more page views. If you need an EXACT ratio, you'll have to back up my solution with a database counter or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will display one of the two pages that will over time, include file4 in a ratio of 4 to 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

```
$randInt = rand (1, 5);

if ($randInt > 1) include("file4.php");
else include("file1.php");
```

Comment: That's the way to go unless you are willing to track inclusion numbers in a persistent way (i.e. database, file etc.).

Comment: Agreed. Good answer for the limited constraints given by OP.

Answer (score -2):

file4.php:

```
$GLOBALS['counter']++;
```

file1.php:

```
$GLOBALS['counter']++;
```

main file:

```
if ($GLOBALS['counter'] % 5 == 0) {
    include('file1.php');
} else {
    include('file4.php');
}
```

But then sit back and wonder why you need this kind of thing.

Comment: `$GLOBALS` is not persisted over requests, so this isn't going to do much. I'm pretty sure the OP wants to do some sort of weighted banner rotator or something similar - one use per pageview, but one of the includes is more likely to happen than the other.

Comment: Probably yeah, but OP didn't give any details, so I'm assuming current request only.

Comment: You can use a text/log file or database even to keep track of how many times a page has been included.  Not sure how that'll affect performance.